# I want to extract gene boundaries(like 1..234, 234..456) from a file using regex in python but every time I use this code it returns me empty list

Tags: python, regex

I want to extract gene boundaries (like 1..234, 234..456) from a file using regex in python but every time I use this code it returns me empty list.

Below is example file

[image: this is the image of file]

Below is what i have so far:

```
import re

#with open('boundaries.txt','a') as wf:
with open('sequence.gb','r') as rf:
    for line in rf:
        x= re.findall(r"^\s+\w+\s+\d+\W\d+",line)
        print(x)
```

Comment: It's always BETTER to attach plain text instead of pictures (now we have to rewrite that to test our anserws).

Answer (score 0):

More suitable pattern would be: `^\s*gene\s*(\d+\.\.\d+)`

Explanation:

`^` - match beginning of a line

`\s*` - match zero or more whitespaces

`gene` - match `gene` literally

`(...)` - capturing group

`\d+` - match one or more digits

`\.\.` - match `..` literally

Then, it's enough to get match from first capturing group to get gene boundaries.

Comment: hi...I was trying it for bigger file with above code only difference is that I used "search" instead of "findall"  its giving me a match but also returning me none values bt I only want matched to be stored in a separate in new file can plz hlp me with this.  the code I used:                      
 import re
with open('file.txt','r') as rf:
    for line in rf:
       
        x= re.search( r"^\s*gene\s*(\d+\.\.\d+)",line)
        print(x)

Answer (score 0):

The pattern does not match, as you are matching a single non word character after matching the first digits that you encounter.

You can repeat matching those 1 or more times.

As you want to have a single match from the start of the string, you can also use re.match without the anchor `^`

```
^\s+\w+\s+\d+\W+\d+
               ^
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zb0xQl/1)

```
import re

s="   gene    1..3256"
pattern = r"\s+\w+\s+\d+\W+\d+"
m = re.match(pattern, s)

if m:
    print(m.group())
```

Output

```
   gene    1..3256
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you used the wrong regex.Try the code below.

```
for line in rf:
    x = re.findall(r"g+.*\s*\d+",line)
    print(x)
```

You can also use online regex 101, to test your regex pattern online.
[online regex 101](https://regex101.com/)